# Load Javascript from Plugin in One Page Only?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, newsletter

I use the  ALO EasyMail Newsletter.
But the plugin is loading lots of Javascript in the head.

I have a mobile site and the scripts are loading in all the pages. I think this affects the mobile performance and want to load it only on the newsletter pages.

How can i do that and load it only in the `/nieuwsbrief` page?

The php starts with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // if logged in ?>
```

Comment: You need to spend some time on writing your question, and framing it properly. Please take a relook. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop this in your `functions.php` or a custom plugin.

```
function wpse_57621_alo_tidy()
{
    if ( $page_id = get_option( 'alo_em_subsc_page' ) ) {
        if ( ! is_page( $page_id ) )
            remove_action( 'wp_head', 'alo_em_ajax_js' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_57621_alo_tidy' );
```

It's attached to the `wp` hook, which runs just after the request has been handled & queried.

We're saying "if the ALO newsletter page setting exists, but we're not currently on said page, unattach the script output hook".